# Find out the fontfamily name or change the chess pieces font at chessboard.sty

Tags: fonts, chessboard

At the chessboard package I tried without success `boardfontfamily={DejaVu Sans}`, but I had to hear this is not a 'fontfamily name'. 
*So what is the generall way to find out the fontfamily name of a font?*

I have 
[image] 
but the chess pieces should look like this: 
[image]

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass[margin=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
%\usepackage{fontspec}% I do not need the whole document in 'DejaVu Sans';
%\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}% however it has no effect too

\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{skak}
\setchessboard{
showmover=false,
% Some tests:
%boardfontfamily={DejaVu Sans}% no effect
%boardfontfamily={dejavu},% no effect
%boardfontfamily=DejaVuSans, % no effect
%boardfontfamily=DejaVuSans-Bold,% no effect
%boardfontfamily=DejaVuSans-Bold-tlf-il2.ttf% no effect
}
\begin{document}
\newgame
\chessboard[]
\end{document}
```

Comment: chess fonts uses a special font encoding and fonts must be prepared for it. "Allowed" family names are described in http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/chessfss/chessfonts_gallery.pdf.  You can setup new fonts but it requires a bit work (I once made for fun a duckchess font: https://github.com/u-fischer/lua-font-pond/blob/master/latex/latex-LSF-LSB-duckchess.pdf, but I don't know if the code still works).

Comment: Aha, that sounds for me, that there is no elementary way to say `boardfontfamily=<another font>` in common.